# UIView presentation layer wrong position after animation

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I have a 'UIView' animated over a `UIBezierPath` with `CAKeyFrameAnimation`.

```
let arcAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
arcAnimation.duration = 0.5

let finalSize : CGFloat = 50
let radiusOffset = CGFloat((position - 1) *  10) + finalSize/2
let radius: CGFloat = 20 * CGFloat(position) + radiusOffset
let center = CGPoint(x:item.bounds.size.width/2 + bounds.size.width/2,
                         y: radius + item.bounds.size.height/2)
let topAngle: CGFloat = .pi * 3/2
    let bottomAngle: CGFloat = .pi/2

let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                            radius: radius,
                            startAngle: bottomAngle,
                            endAngle: topAngle,
                            clockwise: !reverse)

arcAnimation.path = path.cgPath
arcAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
arcAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
arcAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
```

This animation is combined into a `CAAnimationGroup` and everything go fine afterwards. My problem is: when the animation is over, the presentation layer frame has a weird `x` and `y` value for `position`, debugging `view.layer.presentation()?.frame` they all display `(-25.0, -25.0, 50.0, 50.0)` and `view.layer.presentation()?.position` displays `(0,0)`. I need these positions to detect a touch inside the visible area of the animated views.

So my questions are:

Why does it display these values after the animation is finished? How do I get the proper ones?

I'm detecting the touch on the view playing with `hitTest` on `view.layer.presentation()`, any other simpler solution?

Comment: If you specify `isRemovedOnCompletion` as `false`, then the animation is never removed, which maintains the last presentation layer value indefinitely (until you manually remove it). Remove that line and see if that works.

Comment: Yes, That's what I expect, but not what's happening. The **size animation** is kept, but the **position** one isn't. that's the behaviour I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: `CAAnimationGroup` ignores the `isRemovedOnCompletion` parameters for its component animations. I overlooked that you're using an animation group. Try setting `isRemovedOnCompletion` to `false` on the animation group itself.

Comment: are u find the solution ?